# Get name of generic class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a class like this:

```
public class Item<T>
{
   // some properties using T
}
```

Everything works fine, but, I have some views in my MVC project and I need to read the name of the class. When I have a class without Generics it works file, I just use `typeof(Model).Name`  and use it fine. The problem is, when I have a class with a generic `T`, the `.Name` property  of `Type` type, return something like this:

```
 Item`1
```

I would like to read both names in different **strings without work around for remove the ` char**. I want like this:

for a type like this:

```
Item<Product>
```

I would like to get this:

```
string baseClass = "Item";
string genericClass = "Product";
```

how  can I do it?

Comment: No, it is not duplicate, please `READ` my question! READ READ READ \o/  I want it without strings work around, if there is no way, just does not awnser :)

Comment: And what would you like `genericClass` to look like if there is more than one generic parameter, eg `Foo<string,int>` ?

Comment: `class Item` is not the same as `class Item<T>`. So `string baseClass = "Item";` is inaccurate and if you insist on removing detail you'll have to "work with strings".

Comment: Can you include what you would like for `Foo<Bar<int>>` as well?

Comment: How's that different? You don't know how to assign 2 strings to separate objects instead of appending them into one? There's no such thing as base name for Item`1 - every generic version of Item class is a new independent one at compile level.

Comment: Guys, I don't need it for a type like this `Foo<Bar<int>>`, I didn't ask it. I just want to know if is there a way to get the Class and Generic Type in a struct like `Item<T>` without trying to remove the ` char, for me, it sounds like a work around, but ok, if there is no way, let's close the question :)

Comment: Sorry, but is "writing code" considered a workaround nowadays? We aren't talking about a bug here.

Comment: @FelipeOriani The name of the generic type `List<T>` is "List`1", not "List". By removing "``1", you'd have the name of a different or non-existing class. Removing "`1" is not a workaround, because there is no problem to work around.

Comment: Ok guys, I see there is no way :), thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns a string representing the C# declaration for the given type.

It works on most things but there may be one or two edge cases for which it doesn't work correctly. I wrote it a while back, but looking at it now, I think it doesn't support nullables for one.

```
/// Returns a string that can be used as a C# type definition.
string GetTypeDefinition(Type t)
{
    if (t == typeof(void)) return "void";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    string name = t.IsGenericType ? t.FullName.Substring(0, t.FullName.IndexOf("`")) : t.FullName;

    sb.Append(name);

    if (t.IsGenericType)
    {
        sb.Append("<");
        bool first = true;
        foreach(Type genericType in t.GenericTypeArguments)
        {
            if (!first) 
            {
                sb.Append(", ");
            }
            first = false;
            sb.Append(GetTypeDefinition(genericType));
        }
        sb.Append(">");
    }

    if (t.IsArray)
    {
        sb.Append("[]");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you read my question? I want ti without `strings workaround`, I know how to remove the ` char and separate values, but I want a code without workarounds.

Comment: I don't understand your question in that case (and yes, I have read it thoroughly). Please review the comments others have left, and clarify precisely what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I know I can do something like you post on it, but I ask if is there a way to get the names of types without this methods to remove the ` char (need to treat the string) if `Type` type can provide every information separately. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @FelipeOriani there is no such way because every .NET language formats types differently. The CLR does not know anything about C# or VB.NET syntax.